# Cannot add host to icingaweb2

Tags: monitoring

I installed `Icinga2` and `icingaweb2`. I have the dashboard, view of hosts, services, etc. I can log in, log out, etc.

Ok, now I want to monitor something. So I added a host to `/etc/icinga2/conf.d/hosts`, like this:

```
object Host "myhost" {
  display_name "My first host"
  address "X.X.X.X"
  check_command "hostalive"
}
```

Then I reloaded `icinga2` and expected to see `myhost` in Overview/Hosts on the `icingaweb2` dashboard, but despite my efforts all the time I see `0 hosts` and the empty list.

Why icingaweb2 isn't displaying hosts added this way?

Best Regards,
Kamil

Answer (score 1):

I had to run

`sudo icinga2 node wizard`

on the master and other nodes before I saw them in icingaweb2. After running it on the master and hosts you can verify that they are connected with

`sudo icinga2 node list`